# Splash Screen are not shown after adding

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen

I have added the following splash screens to my project (total 3 images):

1. Default.png
2. Default@2x.png
3. Default-568h@2x.png

When I run the app on an iPhone5C, it's not showing any splash screen.

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1, iOS SDK 8.0.

It must automatically take the default screen. I cleaned the project, deleted my previous project on my device and re-run but still no splash screen.

Comment: Did you add them to the asset catalog and did you delete the "Launch Interface File" property in the project settings?

Comment: Please note these aren't splash-screens they are launch images, it might sound silly but there is a difference between the two.

Comment: @Fogmeister Created DemoProject SingleViewApplication Drag and drop three Different size Default Images to the project,  expected launch Images for mobile application after launch on iPhone5c its not appears at all.

Comment: Yeah, you didn't add them to the correct part of the asset catalog and you have the "Launch Interface File" set. You need to fix these.

Comment: @Fogmeister you are correct.  I have to fix these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using an Asset Catalogue for your launch images, which might be what Xcode is expecting. You can see what Xcode is expecting in the General tab for your target:

[image: Launch Image settings]

You should add your launch image to your asset catalogue, and make sure the setting shown is configured correctly.

If you don't have one already, you can add an asset catalogue by going to `File > New > File`, the look under the `Resource` tab.